# Setting color of a xml file programatically

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml background file defined as such:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="true">
<shape android:padding="50dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/sendDarkColorGreen"  android:centerColor="@color/sendDarkColorGreen" android:endColor="@color/sendLightColorGreen" android:angle="90"/>
   <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
</item>
 </selector>
```

This is a background xml file which is applied to a Textview. I want to change the gradient colors of this xml file programatically? How can I do this? I seem to be stumped on this

Comment: It's not possible to modify the resource xml files at runtime. The only way to do what you want would be to use the equivalent Java methods for the various attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the xml file itself.

You could programmatically create a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) and give it a [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html).

Then you set the `StateListDrawable` as the `TextView`'s background.

Comment: Can you please give me a code example? If my xml file is called background.xml for example, how can I set it StateListDrawable?